# Help computing this product through the laguerre polynomial generating function

Tags: generating-functions, orthogonal-polynomials

I don't understand generating functions very well and I was told in one of [my questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1829403/simplifying-this-series-of-laguerre-polynomials) that the coefficient of $t^N$ in the product between $$\frac{1}{(1-t)^2}\,\exp\left(-\frac{tx}{1-t}\right)$$ and $$\frac{2-4t+2t^2-t^2x^2-t^2 x^3}{2t^2 x^2}+\frac{(1-t)(tx+t-1)}{t^2 x^2}\,\exp\left(\frac{tx}{1-t}\right)$$ can be computed through $$\sum_{n\geq 0}L_n(x)\,t^n = \frac{1}{1-t}\,\exp\left(-\frac{tx}{1-t}\right)$$ where $L_n(x)$ is the Laguerre polynomial.  How is this done?

I would be perfectly satisfied with an explanation on how to solve it rather than the solution itself.

Comment: What have attempted?

Comment: I think it should say $t^N$ instead of $x^N$?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I multiplied the two expressions together.  And I've tried to learn more about generating functions, but I got confused and finally decided to ask a new question because I'm kind of desperate for the solution.  I'm also a bit confused why it's $x^N$ and not $t^N$.

Comment: @TyO'Brien: I believe the latter is a typo.

Comment: Okay thank goodness! I had a hunch it might have been but I wasn't sure because I was just learning.

Answer (score 1):

The product is

\begin{align}
&\frac{2-4t+2t^2-t^2x^2-t^2 x^3}{2t^2 x^2(1-t)^2}\exp\left(-\frac{tx}{1-t}\right)+\frac{tx+t-1}{t^2 x^2(1-t)}\\
={}&
\frac{2-4t+2t^2-t^2x^2-t^2 x^3}{2t^2 x^2(1-t)}\sum_{n\ge0}L_n(x)t^n+\frac{tx+t-1}{t^2 x^2(1-t)}
\\
={}&
\frac1{2t^2x^2(1-t)}\left(
\left(2-4t+2t^2-t^2x^2-t^2 x^3\right)\sum_{n\ge0}L_n(x)t^n+2(tx+t-1)\right)
\;.
\end{align}

Except for the factor $1-t$ in the denominator, the coefficient of $t^N$ is straightforward to extract. Multiplying by $1/(1-t)=\sum_kt^k$ sums the coefficients, so the coefficient of $t^N$ is the sum of the coefficients up to and including $t^N$ in the rest of the expression.